# Improving page load when Company has_many Users and I want to show all my companies and users on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization

I have two models, `Company` and `User`. A `Company` has many `Users`.

On one of my pages, I want to display all of my companies and users on a single page:

```
<% @companies.each do |c| %>
  <%= c.name %>
  <% c.users.each do |u| %>
     <%= u.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The only issue is that the page is starting to take 15-30 seconds minimum to load because I have so many companies and users attached to the company. My current solution takes `O(n^2)` (correct me if I'm wrong), so this solution is only going to get worse as my sample grows.

Is there a good way to improve performance? New users are added to company everyday so I have considered caching a hash with the company id as the key and an array of users as the value. Is this a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use **eager loading**.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

In short, if you do something like `Company.includes(:users).find(2)` in your controller, it will perform two queries - one to load the company, and then another to load all of the users all at once. Then you can safely iterate over the users in the view without incurring any extra performance overhead.

This also works if you have a relation of companies, eg. `Company.includes(:users).where(active: true)`. It will load all of the active companies, and all of the users for all of the companies, in just two queries.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Much simpler to do than implement caching :) Thanks